# How to prevent user from altering the id on inspect element in Chrome

Tags: php, jquery

I am just wondering how to prevent user from altering the id on inspect element in Chrome before submitting the result on database. On my website, I created a like button, this button has its own ID such as below (id='1'). Once this button is click, I use ajax to send data on my database and update the columns with the same ID that I passed from ajax. However, if a user change this ID on inspect element in Chrome before submitting the data, they can manipulate my database, and instead of liking the comment with an id=1 they can like other comments, that should not be likable. Is there anyway to prevent this from happening.

```
<input type="button" value="Like" id="1"/>

$('#button').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('like_ajax.php', {id: id}, function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    });

});
```

Comment: you cant, that's why you never trust server side languages

Comment: So what is the different ways to handle this then?

Answer (score 5):

the only solution is to check serverside if the current id is likable or not before saving in db. You should always have these check before saving in DB.

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT (and I repeat DO NOT) trust anything from the client.

Verify and validate before shoving data (the business asset) into a database.

Why not validate and verify the data before it even gets to your prize and glory?

Comment: But I don't really know any kind of verification for a stuff like this. I mean, what else can you verify with these code.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing the user from changing anything on their browser is not quite possible. And, besides, it's the wrong approach to ensuring your data-integrity. Even if there was no way that users could change the values from the `inspect-element` feature, there are several ways that incorrect data can be sent to your server (e.g. making `POST` requests using `javascript`). So, what you need is to perform the validations on the server before persisting the data.

When you receive the data, query the database with the user's `id` and the submitted comment's `id` to make sure that they are actually allowed to do that.

Comment: Can you give me an example of Server side validation for this matter?

Comment: Use the same query that use use to set the `id` of the button on the `client-side`. That query might be returning an array of `id`s that the user is allowed to comment on. When the data is submitted on the server, execute that same query and fetch the same set of `id`s from the database. Check that returned array to ensure that the submitted 'id' is indeed an id the user is allowed to comment on.

Answer (score 0):

**Server side validation** is the right way of handling such scenarios. The permission check should be done in server side for every request so that only the authorized user gets access

Comment: Can you give me an example of Server side validation for this matter?

Answer (score -1):

Try to make a function that could refresh all data from database before the user use it to manipulate your website

Comment: Can you explain further what that means?